# Why some builtin methods in python requires assigning to a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am confused by the Python treats the below examples.

Example 1

```
   >>> a = '{}'
   >>> a.format('1')
   '1'
   >>> a
   '{}'
   >>>
```

Example 2

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
```

In example 1, 'a' is '{}'
In example 2, 'a' is [1]

In both the examples, I'm not assigning the result to 'a', so what's the difference?

Comment: @downvoters: I understand the question provokes downvotes but then conceptually, this question is helpful for beginners. Mutable and non mutable concepts, method call and free functions are concepts that will not come naturally to a beginner. Please consider.

Comment: Also worth explaining to the asker that `a.format()` and `a.append()` are not assignments, it's that format and append are taking 'a' as a parameter but doing so using a dot separator instead of having it within brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering on a broader sense would require a more detail study but for your particular case the difference crops up because one of the object is mutable and the other non-mutable.

You cannot expect to call a method on a `string` and change it. It is supposed to create a new string object.

For the `list.append`, because it is mutable, the method call can update the list in place.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you assigned a is a string which is immutable and the value is `'{}'`, you invoked `format()` to format your string a, a itself is not changed, str.format() returns a copy of the original string where each replacement fields/parts replaced with string values of corresponding argument, in your example, the argument is `'1'`

It is related to the python output, below is quoted from python offical website.

```
>>> print 'We are the {} who say "{}!"'.format('knights', 'Ni')
We are the knights who say "Ni!"
The brackets and characters within them (called format fields) are replaced with the objects passed into the str.format() method.
 A number in the brackets refers to the position of the object passed into the str.format() method.
```

your second example, you initialized a as an empty list and appends an element(call it x) to the end of the list, it is the same as `a[len(a):] = [x]`